# Non ERC 20 coin sent by mistake to MyEtherWallet (MEW)

Tags: blockchain, erc-20, myetherwallet, private-key, sha3

Newbie here - apologies for anything inappropriate and lack of tech expertise.

I made a dumb mistake and sent some THETA tokens to a MEW Ether address. My bad - I had not realised that THETA had moved over to it's own blockchain. The transaction did not go through on Ethereum (I checked on Etherscan) but the tokens somehow ended up in a THETA wallet which got created, with exactly the same public address as the MEW wallet. I can see this at wallet.thetatoken.org

I have been told that I can use my MEW private hex key to access the THETA wallet as they are based on the same SHA 3 hashing. The problem is that I do not have a MEW hex key, just my 24 word seed phrase. There is an "Unlock Your Wallet" option in the THETA wallet, but it seems to only accept a 12 word seed phrase or the hex key itself.

Question: Is there a way I can generate the MEW hex key from my 24 word seed phrase - there was a Reddit post for accessing this via the MEW site, but MEW seemed to have changed the way they do things and no longer provide access to the hex key? Or else is there any other way I could access the THETA wallet using my MEW 24 seed phrase?

Thank you in advance for any guidance.

Comment: Are you basically asking to convert the 24 words mnemonic to a private key?

Comment: Yes, that is probably at the root of this - can I get from my MEW 24 word mnemonic to the specific associated MEW hex private key for that wallet?